# Safely store/modify/delete a string in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm making a project in which I need to store a specific string in my application. I must be able to Store it, Delete it, and Modify it at any given time AFTER the user authenticates, which is done by using the fingerprint API.

If possible, I would like to make sure that ONLY the selected fingerprint, or ONLY the fingerprints that were in the phone before adding this string, will be able to unlock/reveal this string

pop-up windows in which I would like to have the password check for example is as follows:

```
package com.gmtechnology.smartalarm;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;

public class Check_Pass extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        // Get the layout inflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
        // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.check_pass, null))
                // Add action buttons
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.check, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        //Check if the entered string matches the string stored
                        DialogFragment next = new Add_Pass();
                        next.show(getFragmentManager(), "Add_pass");

                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        Check_Pass.this.getDialog().cancel();
                    }
                });
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

This pop-up has an edit text that I can capture the input from to use for the comparison, adding and removing will follow the same pattern. The point here and how to SAFELY store that string and manage it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ADM said use `SharedPreference` to store your String. You can specify if your data is private or public.

> Use 0 or MODE_PRIVATE for the default operation, MODE_WORLD_READABLE and MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE to control permissions.

Have a look at the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String,%20int)) or this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929735/can-shared-preferences-be-private).

In your case, you can make a specific activity (to manipulate your string) only accessible with a Fingerprint authentification.

You should be aware that not all devices are compatible.

Comment: Yes the whole app is fingerprint locked, the main point was to somehow make sure that new fingerprints added to the android system cannot unlock this string. Is there anyway that I could say "I want THIS fingerprint ONLY to be able to unlock my app" no matter how many the user save?

Comment: I am not sure if you can do it with Android Fingerprint API for now(you don't have access to fingerprints). Samsung Fingerprint API is "more" flexible and gives you an idea http://img-developer.samsung.com/onlinedocs/sms/pass/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Safely store what?? Look if you want a persistent storage i.e you need to save it even after your application is closed .then you should use Shared Preference .. Its very easy to use and modify . Or if you want to save it only for once at the runtime of your application then just use a singleton class for it ..

Comment: I am upvoting your answer, however you should polish it a bit. Linking to proper parts of official docs would be good addition.